# implicit __source__ argument to julia macro can't be used within quote block

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

I'll start with my code:

```
    macro example(args...)
        local s = __source__
        println(s)   # This part works, showing macro is called on line 9
        quote
            println(s)   # Julia tells me this variable "s" is not defined
            println(__source__)   # Likewise, "__source__" is not defined here either
        end
    end

    @example 42   # Line 9 of my file
```

In my macro above I want to record the line number that is calling the macro and use it within my quote block. Both capturing it in a variable outside the quote block and using it within, or using it directly in the quote block don't work. My understanding is the code outside the quote block runs at parse-time, and the expression returned from the quote block  is evaluated at run-time.

I feel like there must be a way to capture that variable and inject it right into the expression that will be evaluated later, but I haven't figured out how to do that. Any help here is appreciated. If there is a better way to do this let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding out an answer on my own. In the second line if I changed `__source__` to `__source__.line` or `__source__.file` it worked fine as long as I then used $ to interpolate the result into the expression the macro returned. I'm still not sure why `__source__` on its own didn't work, but using either `.line` or `.file` methods is working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing a similar problem trying to use `__source__`.

I think I can offer insight into why `source.line`, etc worked though.

The value of `source.line` is an integer.  The value of `source.fike` is a string.  Numbers and strings evaluate to themselves.

A symbol, on the other hand, evaluates to whatever value it has in the environment.